# Use a .txt file as the source for text in a marquee where that text file is on Google Drive?

Tags: html, google-drive-api, marquee

I want to use a .txt file located on Google Drive as the source for text for a marquee.  I cannot figure out the correct way to accomplish this.  I want to replace the static text in the following code with my source file.

```
<html>
<head>


     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<!-- CSS Code -->
<style>
.GeneratedMarquee {
font-family:Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:2em;
line-height:1.3em;
color:#ffffff;
background-color:#000000;
padding:.2em;

}
</style>
<body style="background-color:black">
<!-- HTML Code -->
    <video autoplay loop muted playsinline width="90%" height="90%" name="media" class="center">
    <source src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1d5M6i3z0mI5L1mu0kgqdGGi3tiGqHASJ" type='video/mp4'>
    </video>

    <marquee class="GeneratedMarquee" direction="left" scrollamount="8" behavior="scroll">Replace this with txt file on Google Drive</marquee>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: HI there @Jennifer Hamilton! Could you please clarify how you access the file? From what type of device? Is it a public file?

Comment: @Jacques-GuzelHeron I'm simply using a RPi4 and casting the URL to a Chromecast on a TV.  I have a program that outputs a file called output.txt every 60 seconds.  I'd like to be able to have this page read that file and update as a marquee on the TV.  I can either access the file via Google Drive or I can access the sync'd file on my RPi4.  Either way is fine, I just don't know how to use a file as a source for a marquee.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The Google Drive API allows you to create apps that leverage Google Drive cloud storage. You can develop applications that integrate with Google Drive, and create robust functionality in your application using Google Drive API.

Google drive API is not intended for use as a file server. Its simply a file storage system. What you are trying to do is not going to work.  There will be no way for you to authorize someone clicking on that link to be able to access the file.

You should look at storing the files on your own file server.

Comment: @DalmTo I'm not trying to allow access to the file.  I'm simply trying to display the contents of the file on a html page.

Comment: Google drive api does not have access to the contents of files in that manner.  Its just file storage.  Even the Google docs api is going to give you access to edit the data inside of a google doc it wont display it for you.   your going to have to download the file to your server and then code something to open the file and display the contentce.